# trigger a build only when tag is pushed in jenkins pipeline 2x

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a requirement where when I commit and push a tag, it should trigger a build automatically on jenkins where I have a project containing the jenkins script. 
I used below scripts but it triggers the build for the commits as well:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: [[name: '*/tags/*-0.STAGE']],

     extensions: [],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://abc@gitrepo.git',
    credentialsId: 'admin/******', 
    refspec: '+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*' ]],
    poll: true]
```

It seems a very important feature but even after a lot of combinations, I am unable to move on. I set the Jekins job's Build trigger with Poll SCM. I am using the BitBucket Branch Source plugin.

For reference, I went through the filed defects of the jenkins
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14917
and
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34395

Comment: Are you sure branches syntax right ? Why don't you try with REGEX style.

Comment: yes, it is correct. I used the same in the earlier version where pipeline was not there. The problem here is, it triggers the build for all the commits, I want it only for tags.

Comment: Documentation says:
<tagName>
This does not work since the tag will not be recognized as tag.
Use refs/tags/<tagName> instead.

Comment: Samy, i also think so, but it was feasible in jenkins 1x with github. Why bitbucket has such issues?